# Migração, retirar acentos de todos os nomes de uma coluna na base de dados

Tags: php, string

Eu quero fazer uma modificação numa serie de dados de uma coluna na base de dados, retirar os acentos para estou a fazer essa função em php. O problema é que nenhuma das funções que descobri resulta. O estranho disto é que se escrevermos diretamente `removeAccents('inês')` , por ex, já funciona mas se escrevermos `removeAccents($_POST['heya']);` sendo que `$_POST['heya'] = 'inês'` (exemplo) já não resulta.

PHP:

```
function removeAccents($str) {
  $a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ẽ', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý','Ç', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ẽ', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ', 'Ά', 'ά', 'Έ', 'έ', 'Ό', 'ό', 'Ώ', 'ώ', 'Ί', 'ί', 'ϊ', 'ΐ', 'Ύ', 'ύ', 'ϋ', 'ΰ', 'Ή', 'ή', '…', '.', '\'', ',');
  $b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y','C', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o', 'Α', 'α', 'Ε', 'ε', 'Ο', 'ο', 'Ω', 'ω', 'Ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'Υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'Η', 'η', '', '', '', '');
  return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}

if(isset($_POST['heya2'])) {
  echo removeAccents($_POST['heya']);
  echo '<br>';
  echo strtr($_POST['heya'],'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ','aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input name="heya" type="text">
  <input name="heya2" type="submit">
</form>
```

No exemplo acima, o output das duas funções de "inês" sai exatamente igual, "inês".

Na função para modificar a base de dados acontece o mesmo:

```
$dataBase = new DB($db);

$projects = $dataBase->fetchAllProjectsByDisplayOrder();
foreach($projects as $p) {
  $shortName = strtolower(str_replace('_','-', removeAccents($p->short_name)));
  //$dataBase->updateShortNameMigra2($p->id, $shortName);
  echo $shortName. '<br>';
}
```

Em baixo está uma imagem do que acontece com este código. Alguma maneira de resolver isso, retirar os acentos?

[image: printscreen]

Comment: Qual o motivo para remover os acentos? É para gerar links de SEO ou outra coisa específica?

Comment: Exato é para o URL ficar mais limpo. Em vez de `...project.php?name=Ao_Ritmo_Da_ProduÇÃo` por exemplo

Comment: eu testei seu script a função removeAccents() funcionou aqui. Só o strtr que deu problema.

Comment: Não percebo mesmo. A função resulta se escvrever-mos a string diretamente, `echo strtolower(str_replace('_','-', removeAccents('Inês')));`, mas se a escrevermos `...strtolower(str_replace('_','-', removeAccents($_POST['heya'])));` já não dá. Vi agora que ao agarrar da base de dados também acontece o mesmo, se escrevermos "Ao_Ritmo_Da_ProduÇÃo" diretamente funciona, mas não como variável

Comment: Com o iconv passa-se o mesmo, se `$output = 'Ao_Ritmo_Da_ProduÇÃo';
$foo = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$output);`, resulta, mas se a variável não vier diretamente do script já não... `...iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$p->short_name); // neste caso $p->short_name = Ao_Ritmo_Da_ProduÇÃo` já não dá

Comment: certifique-se sobre a configurações de charset tanto dos dados no banco de dados quanto dos scripts php.

Comment: Está tudo certinho (UTF-8)

Comment: Pessoal descobri o que se passava, está em baixo. Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui. Despois de pensar e dar umas voltas à cabeça descobri que como eu enviava os dados para a base de dados como entidades HTML com a função `htmlentities()` por segurança (ex: `htmlentities(só) = s&oacute;`) quando os vou buscar os dados à base de dados eles não têm acentos, ou seja, a função `removeAccents()` não fazia nada porque nenhuma palavra tem acentos, eles só passavam a existir no browser onde essa função já não era executada, tenho de fazer o decode (`html_entity_decode()`) no server primeiro e tirar os acentos depois:

```
foreach($projects as $p) {
  echo removeAccents(html_entity_decode($p->short_name)). '<br>';
}
```